I can't see my rig!
My character has a rig but I can't see it in Object mode, Pose mode, I checked if the rig is hidden and it is visible when I look on the right. 

if my answer doesn't help, pls provide blend file. thx.


Click on "selectability & visibility" and check whether armature is unchecked.

Thank you, I'll check if it works. :3
